# Using Worksheet.Change event to add a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of cells (specifically D6:D34) where all the values in the cells have a corresponding sheet. However, since I've been just manually adding worksheets when I add a new value (or change a cell value), I'm thinking about using `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)` to allow the automatic creation of a worksheet when the cells change. This is what I've tried to use, but now I'm getting an error that the "sheet name already exists" as it looks down the whole column. I've tried using error handling to skip over ones that exist, but it ends up moving to the next one to check but leaving "Sheet1" and "Sheet2", etc. Any suggestions on how to set this up?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim hlValue As Range
For Each hlValue In Sheets(1).Range("D6:D34")
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = hlValue
Next
End Sub
```

I should also say that if one of the cell value is deleted, the worksheet should be deleted as well. Some sort of `If CellValue <> Exist, Delete`? I couldn't find anything to use to check if it exists besides fancy functions. Should I use one of these?

EDIT: Okay, I've got this now. This should suffice.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Run faster
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Just in case
Dim shtName As Variant
For Each shtName In Sheets(1).Range("D6:D34")
If WorksheetExists((shtName)) Then
'do nothing
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
     ActiveSheet.Name = shtName
Application.StatusBar = "Creating new sheet for " & shtName 'Just in case it's running slowly
Sheets("Admin").Select
End If
Next
Application.StatusBar = "READY"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
Function WorksheetExists(sName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I couldn't find anything to use to check if it exists besides fancy functions. Should I use one of these?

Yes, you should! Worksheets are part of a `Collection` object and there is no built-in `Exists` (or similar) method that you can query. Such a function is not fancy :) and it would be a good introduction to using functions and/or calling other subroutines, if you're not familiar with that already.

At it's simplest:

```
Function SheetExists(sName As String) As Boolean
    Dim w as Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set w = Worksheets(sName)
    SheetExists = Not w Is Nothing
End Function
```

How this works:

```
If SheetExists("sheet1") Then
    'Do something
Else
    'Sheet doesn't exist, so do something else
End If
```

You pass a string value to the function as `sName`. THe function then returns `True` or `False` whether this sheet exists.

First, the function `SheetExists` attempts to set a `Worksheet` variable to the specified worksheet, by name. This will predictably fail if the worksheet name doesn't exist, so we use this knowledge along with the `Resume Next` statement. In the case of an error, `w` will not be assigned a worksheet and will remain a `Nothing`, and then we use a boolean expression (`Not w Is Nothing`) as the function's return value.  If the sheet *does* exist, `w` will not be nothing, so the function will return `True`, and if the sheet doesn't exist, `w` will be `Nothing`, so the function will return `False`.

The function above only uses the `ActiveWorkbook`, so a more robust version of this would also allow you to specify a parent workbook.

```
Function SheetExists(sName As String, Optional wb as Workbook = Nothing) As Boolean
    'This function checks whether worksheet 'sName' exists in 
    ' workbook object 'wb'. If no parameter is passed for 'wb' then 
    ' assume to use the ActiveWorkbook
    Dim w as Worksheet
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set w = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    SheetExists = Not w Is Nothing
End Function
```

**NB:** There are relatively few cases where `On Error Resume Next` is not frowned upon, but using this in a very small and specific Function, with a well-defined purpose and expectation is OK.

Alternatively, brute force iteration over the collection's Items may also be used to query collections for existence, and this does not rely on `On Error Resume Next`:

```
Function SheetExists2(sName as String) As Boolean
    Dim ws as Worksheet, ret as Boolean
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = sName Then
            ret = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    SheetExists2 = ret
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, David! I really appreciate it. Personally I love the utilizing of error handling so I'm definitely not frowning upon it.